# Including a .bib file with \input does not work

Tags: unicode, external-files, input, font-encodings

In the following simple document, the bibliography does not work :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage{inputenc}

\inputencoding{utf8}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
\input{references_utf8}
\end{filecontents}
\inputencoding{latin1}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite[voir][chap. 12]{2009solar}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

I want to do this because my main documents are in latin-1 and the .bib file is in utf-8. The idea of using `\inputencoding` was recommended in this question : [How to convert UTF-8 to latin-1 on the fly?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67856/how-to-convert-utf-8-to-latin-1-on-the-fly).

The file references_utf8.bib looks like this :

```
@book{2009solar,
address = {New Delhi},
author = {Solanki, Chetan Singh},
booktitle = {Solar Photovoltaics: Fundamentals, Technologies and Applications},
chapter = {12},
edition = {1},
isbn = {9788120337602},
pages = {478},
publisher = {Prentice-Hall of India},
title = {{Solar Photovoltaics: Fundamentals, Technologies and Applications}},
url = {http://books.google.ca/books?id=hdvYA9KsI2YC},
year = {2009}
}
```

But it has to be encoded in utf-8.

How can I make this setup work?

Comment: it does make sense to input a bib. Put the \inputencoding command before the \bibliography command (which loads the bbl)

Comment: I think I narrowed down the problem : commands like \input{references_utf8} inside the environment filecontents are NOT executed by latex, but simply copied verbatim in the file \jobname.bib. This is not what I want : If the command culd be executed, I think the whole code would work.

Comment: No. You are on the completly wrong track. You don't need a `\jobname.bib`. bibtex will use your original `references.bib` to create a `\jobname.bbl`. And your document will then input this `bbl` when you use the `\bibliography` command. Open the bib and the bbl in your editor to see the differences!

Comment: If your bib file is as you show with all ascii characters you do _not_ need any encoding switch. That file is already ascii, utf8 and latin1: the encodings are identical in that range. What made you think you needed to change the input encoding?

Answer (score 2):

`bibtex` cannot handle utf8 characters. With `bibtex8` *some* utf8 characters are possible, eg umlauts. However, you can change the inputencoding:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\cite[voir][chap. 12]{2009solar}

\begingroup
\iputencoding{utf8}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: As you can see, the .bib file does not contain any special characters. It seems to be simply a matter of what type of encoding is specified in the file (is this how it works? is there a "specified type"?). In my .bib file, if I have special special characters they will we coded with the latex command. For example, é will be coded \'{e} so this should not be a problem.

Comment: it should be coded as `{\'e}`